# Flex: MXML syntax highlighting, autocomplete and bracket matching functionality on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, apache-flex, ide

Has anyone been able to get syntax highlighting, autocomplete and bracket matching functionality on GNU/Linux for MXML files?

We are using Eclipse with [Flex Builder for Linux](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flex/flexbuilder_linux/) (version alpha 5), but we can't edit MXML files on design view, and the text mode just shows the XML as plain text (not even syntax highlighting).

The official project from Adobe seems abandoned, do you know of any alternatives?

**UPDATE**
As James Ward comments:

> Make sure you vote for this feature
>   request:
>   http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-19053

Comment: Can you post any errors in the workspace/.metadata/.log file?  FB for Linux alpha 5 is working fine for me.  But if you are on Eclipse 3.5 then you need to apply a few patches.

Comment: Did you get the design view working with version alpha 5? We can run the app from Eclipse, and edit ActionScript, but not MXML files.

Comment: Design view doesn't work in FB for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JetBrains just launched [IntelliJ IDEA version 9](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/).
Which has Flex and Air support. Take a look at it.

Comment: I tried the 30 day trial, and it works pretty much as expected. But the licence costs are way expensive for something I can do with an older version of Eclipse. It looks pretty good anyways.

Answer (score 0):

So far, **IntelliJ IDEA version 9** and **Eclipse** with **Flex Builder** seem to be the best solutions for this question.

We were using Eclipse 3.5, but haven't been able to use the MXML syntax highlight or autocomplete even with the patches. However, we could use these features with Eclipse Europa without patches.

The Design view for MXML doesn't work for GNU/Linux yet, afaik.

I hope this situation improves.

Comment: Make sure you vote for this feature request: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-19053